# Create tables in Glue Data Catalog for data in S3 and unknown schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

My current use case is, in an ETL based service (`NOTE`: The ETL service is not using the Glue ETL, it is an independent service), I am getting some data from AWS Redshift clusters into the S3. The data in S3 is then fed into the T and L jobs. I want to populate the metadata into the Glue Catalog. The most basic solution for this is to use the Glue Crawler, but the crawler runs for approximately 1 hour and 20 mins(lot of s3 partitions). The other solution that I came across is to use Glue API's. However, I am facing the issue of data type definition in the same.

Is there any way, I can create/update the Glue Catalog Tables where I have data in S3 and the data types are known only during the extraction process.

But also, when the T and L jobs are being run, the data types should be readily available in the catalog.

Comment: How many tables are present in your usecase?

Comment: There will be many tables, the glue catalog will serve only as a catalog for the data being populated into the S3. 
There will be around 100 jobs running generating 500-600 gbs of data in a single day.

Comment: Got some leads, the redshift "CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS" will be useful while creating a new table, which will load the data into the S3 as well. When there will be updates in the table, like new partitions addition, then I will be using the Athena MSCK REPAIR TABLE to get the partitions in the table.

However, I am still looking for an optimised solution, as MSCK will not scale well and the run time will increase as the size of dataset increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to the problem, I ended up utilising the Glue Catalog API's to make it seamless and fast.
I created an interface which interacts with the Glue Catalog, and override those methods for various data sources. Right after the data has been loaded into the S3, I fire the query to get the schema from the source and then the interface does its work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and publish the solution?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create, update the data catalog during your ETL process, you can make use of the following:

**Update**:

```
additionalOptions = {"enableUpdateCatalog": True, "updateBehavior": "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE"}
additionalOptions["partitionKeys"] = ["partition_key0", "partition_key1"]

sink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(frame=last_transform, database=<dst_db_name>,
                                                    table_name=<dst_tbl_name>, transformation_ctx="write_sink",
                                                    additional_options=additionalOptions)
job.commit()
```

The above can be used to update the schema. You also have the option to set the `updateBehavior` choosing between `LOG` or `UPDATE_IN_DATABASE` ([default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-configure-changes-api)).

**Create**

To create new tables in the data catalog during your ETL you can follow this example:

```
sink = glueContext.getSink(connection_type="s3", path="s3://path/to/data",
                           enableUpdateCatalog=True, updateBehavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
                           partitionKeys=["partition_key0", "partition_key1"])
sink.setFormat("<format>")
sink.setCatalogInfo(catalogDatabase=<dst_db_name>, catalogTableName=<dst_tbl_name>)
sink.writeFrame(last_transform)
```

You can specify the database and new table name using `setCatalogInfo`.

You also have the option to **update the partitions** in the data catalog using the `enableUpdateCatalog` argument then specifying the `partitionKeys`.

A more detailed explanation on the functionality can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/update-from-job.html).

Comment: Isn't this approach for when your ETL jobs are on Glue only? My ETL jobs are not running on the Glue.

Comment: It is for Glue. Your question had asked for Glue data catalog. Maybe if you can be more specific then maybe you could get a more accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I will add this in the question and rephrase it.